# Copy and PasteSpecial Table Values and Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I am still new with VBA but decided using VBA to streamline a Monthly report I am working on for our payroll would be the most efficient way, I wish to export a range I3:U2270 into a new sheet named from a cell in the summary sheet. Everything works fine except formatting.

If I use `xlPasteAll` the formatting is perfect, but it shows values as formulas.

If I use:

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

The data and cell widths are perfect, but because some data is in Tables, it doesn't bring the formatting across.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
Sub MonthlySummaryExport()
     
    Dim NewSheetName As String
    Dim Newsheet As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    NewSheetName = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T1")
    If NewSheetName = "" Then Exit Sub
        Set Newsheet = Sheets(NewSheetName)
        If Not Newsheet Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sheet cannot be created as there is already a worksheet with the same name" & " " & (NewSheetName)
            Exit Sub
            End If
            Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = NewSheetName
            
    'Copy and PasteSpecial a between worksheets
    Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("I3:U2270").Copy
    
    With Worksheets(NewSheetName).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With

    'Disable marching ants around copied range
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy everything including formulas, then change formulas to values in the copy

```
'Copy and PasteSpecial a between worksheets
    dim dest as range
    set dest = Worksheets(NewSheetName).Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("I3:U2270").Copy dest
    dest.currentregion.copy
    dest.pastespecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that on my data and the formatting copied across perfectly but it didn't change the formulas to values? any ideas?

Comment: If A1 has blank cells around it then dest.currentregion.copy would fail. Try  dest.parent.usedrange.copy instead

Comment: Still no luck with the following - seems strange! `'Copy and PasteSpecial a between worksheets
    Dim dest As Range
    Set dest = Worksheets(NewSheetName).Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("I3:U2270").Copy dest
    dest.Parent.UsedRange.Copy
    dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`